# I am trying to make a purely Intraday simple strategy based on HA Candles with VWAP and RSI as key indicators with a trailing SL

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to make a simple strategy based on HA Candles with VWAP and RSI as key indicators with a trailing SL.

The idea is that Candle (-2) opens below VWAP and Closes above VWAP. The next Candle, i.e., Candle (-1) is a confirmation candle which opens above VWAP and Closes also above. Both Candles are Green Candles.

I enter into trade at the opening of Candle (0). Here I would also want to take into consideratin the RSI which too should be on the up (rising). I woould like to be flexible in the RSI lookback. It can be a lookback of one candle or three candles.

Regarding Profit booking/Trailing StopLoss, The SL is fixed at the opening of Candle (-1). Now if when the profit level reaches (say 5%)  the SL should move to cost level and if the profit moves still up, then the SL should move to 2% above the buy price. This is for CE. The opposite would be for PE. I am finding that many times, the RSI conditions are not met and the trade is entered into (for eg. the RSI is on down and LE in CE is made and many times RSI is on up and LE on PE is made) and many times, the Loss booked is much more than what I want it to be.

I have tried to make the following strategy. I want the strategy to work on Options.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Stg 1", overlay=true)

stag = input(defval = '', title = 'Custom Strategy Tag', type = input.string)

max_orders = input(defval = 3, title = "Max Trades per Day", type = input.integer, minval = 1)
strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders(max_orders*2)

len = input(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length")
src = input(close, "RSI Source", type = input.source)    

up  = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)

rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

vwap1 = vwap(open)

plot(vwap1,color=color.white)

rl = input(title="RSI LookBack",defval=3)

//============================= adding stoploss and target option============================================================

tar_sl = input(title = "===================Qty/Target/SL Settings==================",  defval = true   , type = input.bool)

longProfitPerc = input(title="Long Take Profit (%)",type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=6) * 0.01
shortProfitPerc = input(title="Short Take Profit (%)",type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=6) * 0.01
tarl  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + longProfitPerc)
tars = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - shortProfitPerc)

longTrailPerc = input(title="Trail Long Loss (%)",type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=7) * 0.01 

shortTrailPerc = input(title="Trail Short Loss (%)", type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=7) * 0.01 

trailLong = strategy.position_avg_price * longTrailPerc
trailLong := trailLong +strategy.position_avg_price

trailShort = strategy.position_avg_price * shortTrailPerc
trailShort := abs(trailShort - strategy.position_avg_price)

hopen = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open)
hclose = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)
buy_signal = rsi > rsi[rl] and hclose[1]> vwap1 and hopen[1]<vwap1 and hclose>hopen and hopen>vwap1

sell_signal = rsi < rsi[rl] and hclose[1] < vwap1 and hopen[1]> vwap1 and hclose<hopen and hopen<vwap1
stopl  = valuewhen(buy_signal,open[1],0) 
stops = valuewhen(sell_signal,open[1],0)
```

Comment: What does your code do presently? Can you show what output/result/error you are getting?

Comment: Good morning and thanks for the help. my idea is that the trade should be entered into when both (VWAP and RSI) conditions are met and that the SL (trailing or otherwise) should be strictly followed. What it means is that CE should be entered when VWAP is met also RSI is on the up.  What is happening sometimes is that CE is entered into even when the RSI movement from the lookback period is on the down. And in PE, the same error in opposite is happening which should not happen in both conditions. Also, SL doesn't get triggered at the desired %age ( it overshoots a lot) nor does it get trailed